# Real analysis: prove $\;\lim_{x\to -1} x^3 + x -2 = -4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that $\lim_{x\to -1} x^3 + x -2 = -4$

My try is the following:
To begin, note that if x is a real number, satisfies (sth that I need help with), then (sth that I need help with).

Now, for ε>0 given, define  δ = min{sth, sth},
Then, if $0<-sth-<δ,$
it follows that $|x^3+x+2| = |(x+1)*(x^2-x+2)|<=(|x|+1)*(|x^2-x+2|)....sth$ that I need help with

When you see sth, it means I need your help on that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to show that $\lim_{x\to-1}x^{3}+x-2=-4$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$,

$|(x^{3}+x-2)-(-4)|=|x^{3}+x+2|=|x+1||x^{2}-x+2|\le|x+1|(|x|^{2}+|x|+2)$

First assume $|x|-1\le|x+1|<1$ so that $|x|<2$. This tells us the above is bounded by:

$|x+1|(4+2+2)=8|x+1|$

Now if $|x+1|<\frac{\epsilon}{8}$ then the above is bounded by $\epsilon$. Hence, if we choose $0<|x+1|<\delta<\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{8}\}$ then $|(x^{3}+x-2)-(-1)|<\epsilon$. $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary.

Comment: $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{8}\}$. ?

Comment: Also how do you come up with this $|x|-1\le|x+1|<1$ Especially how do you decide the right hand side is 1 not other number and same to the left hand side too

Comment: You can take $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{8}\}$. I used the reverse triangle inequality which states $|x|-|y|\le|x-y|$. Notice that $|x+1|=|x-(-1)|$.

Comment: How about the one on the right hand side? Could you pick other number other than 1?

Comment: Yes you can take another number but the estimate on $|x|^{2}+|x|+2$ may change. For example if we only require that $|x+1|<2$ then the same estimating process as in the proof only guarantees $|x|-1<2$ so $|x|<3$. This implies $|x|^{2}+|x|+2<9+3+2=14$. So we will have to take $\delta=\min\{2,\frac{\epsilon}{14}\}$.